# Does it need synchronization if a thread class has just one instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Referring to this topic([How to pause Thread execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058395/how-to-pause-thread-execution)), Peter Knego said:

> Loop must be inside synchronized block.

But I don't see the point of synchronization if only one instance is there.

In another case, if the thread class has multiple instances and they are copping with different variables, does the loop need to be synchronized.

Actually, I wrote a few programs using threads (with multiple instances) without considering synchronization and they works fine.

Comment: which topic? Cannot see any link or code?

Comment: Depends on whether the thread or threads need to synchronise with something doesn't it...

Comment: 1. Threads don't have instances, much like files don't have instances. They just *are* threads. 2. "they works fine" doesn't prove anything beyond that they worked for you in the particular runs you have observed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I modified the question. For instance, I mean instances of the same thread class. You may correct me if the statement is still inappropriate.

Comment: It is essential to distinguish the `Thread` class and its instances from the actual threads of execution. `new Thread` doesn't create a thread. Also, as far as thread-safety, the type of the `Thread` subclass is irrelevant. Having two instances of the same class is the same as involving two different classes.

Comment: We are talking here about a case where one thread controls another. That means we have state that is shared between two threads, so we need to synchronize access to it. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must synchronize any access to shared state. If all of your instances access local storage, then they are thread safe. If your methods are thread safe, they do not require synchronization. If you had a static (e.g. global) resource, and modified it in multiple threads then that is likely to be non-thread safe (excluding atomic operations of course).

Comment: Your answer sounds like what I want. That is to say both cases I mentioned won't require synchronization, right?

Comment: If there is only one thread of execution, then you don't need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

The answer says

Use synchronized, wait() and notify() for that.

1. Create an atomic flag (e.g. boolean field) in the thread to be stopped. Stoppable thread monitors this flag in the loop. Loop must be inside `synchronized` block.
2. When you need to stop the thread (button click) you set this flag.
3. Thread sees the flag is set and calls `wait()` on a common object (possibly itself).
4. When you want to restart the thread, reset the flag and call `commonObject.notify()`.

You cannot call wait() or notify on an object unless you get a lock on it's monitor. And putting it inside synchronized block is a way to do that.

Comment: I checked java doc, although not fully understand it yet, I see your point.

Comment: It is very simple to understand. You can start or stop your vehicle only if you have the control of it. Similarly you cannot call wait() and notify() on threads/objects unless you acquire lock over their monitors.

Comment: Hey, can you see these two links for me? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334207/using-notify-wait-instead-of-suspend-and-resume-to-control-a-t/13334493#13334493), (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254433/best-method-to-pause-a-thread), both at the uppermost example. They both use a LOCK object and a bollean pauseFlag. There are differences there, and Gray's example is more intelligible. Which one is better?

Comment: Both are nearly same except use of atomic flag by Gray. Google about atomic variables in java to know more.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the `wait` and `notify` are part of the [condition variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variable#Condition_variables) and using them without synchronizing on them leads in the general use-case to race conditions

the normal way of using wait is

```
synchronized(this){
    while(someCondition())
       wait();//while loop is needed to combat spurious wakeups
}
```

and you wake it up with

```
synchronized(this){
    adjustCondition();
    notify();
}
```

if you didn't synchronize on the condition as well then you get into a race for example

you just tested `someCondition()` and got `true` so you need to wait. but before you get a chance to another thread executes the `adjustCondition();notify();` block

but the first thread will still enter the `wait()` (because the condition has already been checked) and which may lead to deadlock

Answer (score -1):

The Thread monitor needs to be synchronized in your case. This is done only for the actual wait call, because it requires that. I recommend to have a special wait Object for this to not accidental synchronize on something else.

```
final static Object threadPauseMonitor = new Object();
// ...
while (shouldPause.get()) {
  synchronized(threadPauseMonitor) {
    threadPauseMonitor.wait();
  }
}
```

Where `shouldPause` is an AtomicBoolean. Please note the `while` to counter the malicious *spurious wakeup* that can possibly occur.

Comment: This is broken. The signal could occur after we check `shouldPause.get` and before we call `threadPauseMonitor.wait`, leading to waiting forever for something that has already happened.